# How do I generate a div with select-option tags and some button on the click on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

So I have this code:
I want the generated div to be append to the div with class 'members' I also have two button: one to generate the div and the other to submit. My console shows me no error but the code won't just work and it will freeze my browser Any help??

HTML:

```
<main>
        <div class="members">

        </div>
        <form>
            <button class="addMember" type="button">Add Member <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> </button>
            <button type="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </main>
```

JS:

```
const generateDOM = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const memEl = document.createElement('div');
    memEl.classList.add("member")
    const counter = document.createElement('input');
    const num = document.createElement('input');
    const mem = document.createElement('select');
    let memOpt = document.createElement('option');
    const removeButton = document.createElement('button');

    //  setup the drop-down members
    for (let i = 0; i < totalInheritors.length; i++) {
        memOpt.value = totalInheritors[i];
        memOpt.text = totalInheritors[i];
        memOpt.classList.add('member-name')
        mem.appendChild(memOpt);
    }
    mem.classList.add('member-group')
    memEl.appendChild(mem);

    // setup the removeButton
    removeButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    removeButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
    memEl.appendChild(removeButton);

    // setup counter attributes
    counter.setAttribute('type', 'range');
    counter.min = 1;
    counter.max = 10;
    counter.classList.add('mem-range')
    memEl.appendChild(counter);

    // setup counter attributes
    num.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    num.min = 1;
    num.max = 10;
    num.classList.add('mem-num')
    memEl.appendChild(num);

    // setting DOM elements
    memContainer.appendChild(memEl);
};
```

Note I wanna generate my options from an array of strings
And I think the problem is with the loop, Any guide for a reasonable loop?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. There are several issues with your code or you did not include it in the posted code: 1.) you do not bind the method to the button. 2.) `totalInheritors` and `memContainer` are not declared 3.) `e.preventDefault` only needs to be set on `<input type="submit">`, not on a normal button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question there are several issues with the posted code which either need to be fixed or are hopefully already implemented but have not been posted in your code snippet. The main problem I see in your code is that you only create one `<option>` element and only update its value and text in the loop instead of creating one `<option>` element per entry.

So instead of:

```
let memOpt = document.createElement('option');
// ...

//  setup the drop-down members
for (let i = 0; i < totalInheritors.length; i++) {
    memOpt.value = totalInheritors[i];
    memOpt.text = totalInheritors[i];
    memOpt.classList.add('member-name')
    mem.appendChild(memOpt);
}
```

move the declaration into the loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < totalInheritors.length; i++) {
  let memOpt = document.createElement('option');
  memOpt.value = totalInheritors[i];
  memOpt.text = totalInheritors[i];
  memOpt.classList.add('member-name')
  mem.appendChild(memOpt);
}
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/4so0ptam/) to demonstrate the above.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.